# Where does the NDK look for libraries?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Suppose I want to compile with the NDK a c++ function that in its body calls a function in a library (like STL, etc). How to tell the NDK where in my pc is the library so that when compiling my c++ function the NDK will make the jump when the function in the library is called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify your libraries in your `Android.mk` file.

For the standard library, you only have to specify in your `Application.mk` which one you want to use, i.e.:

```
APP_STL=gnustl_shared
```

for the GCC standard library.

For your other libraries, you have to put in your `Android.mk` file which library you want to use, and tell the ndk to build them if necessary.

For an already build library, put

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE=<give a name to the lib you want to link>
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES=<path to your lib include directory>
LOCAL_SRC_FILE=<path to your library binary file>


include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY) #or STATIC if your lib is static
```

For a library that must be build, put

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE=<give a name to the lib you want to link>
LOCAL_SRC_FILE=<list all the files necessary to build your lib>
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES=<path to your lib include directory>

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY) #or STATIC if you want to build it static
```

Then, after doing that, just add the following

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES=<list your static libs **using their LOCAL_MODULE names**>

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES=<list your shared libs **using their LOCAL_MODULE names**>
```

and voila!